# Align three columns without unnecessary whitespace

Tags: equations, align, split

I have a rather long and complicated equation that I wish to present in a nicely split manner. I wish to use what amounts to a basic structure with three columns. Line two is meant to start in column 3, and line 3 is meant to start in column 2. I have checked other topics and tried various environments, among them alignedat, split, multiline and array. Nothing worked because every time, I get a new format issue. The most prominent one is that there is a huge whitespace after `[` where I want column 3 to start.

My current attempt is this:

```
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{array}{rll}
        \delta(t) =& \int_{t_0}^{t}[&f_\mathrm{I}(\tau, \eta(\tau)+\delta(\tau)) + f_\mathrm{E}(\tau, \eta(\tau)+\delta(\tau))] -\\
        &&[f_\mathrm{I}(\tau, \eta(\tau)) + f_\mathrm{E}(\tau, \eta(\tau))] d\tau +\\
        &E(t, \eta).
    \end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

Which ends up looking like this:

[image]

Similar attempts with other environments produced similar, or even uglier results.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you really need $E(t,\eta)$ on a third line?

Comment: In this case I'd use `align*` instead of `equation*` and I'd make the first "row" using `aligned`

Comment: @daleif: or, more simply, `alignat*`.

Comment: @Bernard there isn't any need here., the last line disturbs the dual alignment, much easier to just use `align*` + `aligned`

Comment: @daleif: or `\mathrlap`.

Comment: @Bernard that just makes things even more complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is what I'd do. Note that the `aligned` part does not include the `\int` otherwise this gives too much space between the first two rows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \delta(t) = {} &
  \int_{t_0}^{t}
  \begin{aligned}[t]
   &[f_\mathrm{I}(\tau, \eta(\tau)+\delta(\tau)) + f_\mathrm{E}(\tau, \eta(\tau)+\delta(\tau))] \\
    &-[f_\mathrm{I}(\tau, \eta(\tau)) + f_\mathrm{E}(\tau,
    \eta(\tau))] d\tau
  \end{aligned}
  \\
  &+E(t, \eta).
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is, although a bit more verbose than what I would've liked, exactly what I needed. Thank you! What is the best way to nest this in an equation environment in case I want to number and reference it?

Comment: @J.Grünenwald replace `align*` with another `aligned` (they can be nested), then wrap the entire thing with `equation`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `alignat*`and `\mathrlap`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
        \delta(t) & =& & \int_{t_0}^{t}&[ & f_\mathrm{I}(\tau, \eta(\tau)+\delta(\tau)) + f_\mathrm{E}(\tau, \eta(\tau)+\delta(\tau))] -{}\\[-1ex]
         & && & [ & f_\mathrm{I}(\tau, \eta(\tau)) + f_\mathrm{E}(\tau, \eta(\tau))] d\tau +{}\\
 & & &\mathrlap{E(t, \eta).}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]